# What are "touch-up sets", and are they really important?

Tags: muscle-mass, sets

Jeff is a good guy, but sometimes I just don't get what he's [saying](https://youtu.be/RjexvOAsVtI?t=205). What are "touch-up sets", and are they really important? Why? I struggle to understand even the first sentence

> With a touchup set we’re trying to overreach with 10% of what we’re going to do in our first working set, to our five-rep max. What we do is a box squat.
> The box squat will allow us to get down there, to feel the safety, to have the confidence
> that we have a bottom point.
> It will give us that biofeedback to know ‘that’s what I’m heading for’. Give it a one or two rep touch, come back up, then start your working sets. What does that do, neurologically?
> That overreach allows us to feel more ready and able to attack our working sets with a
> lighter weight. This, what would normally be our heavier weight, has now become lighter by the performance
> of that one set. Neurologically, it’s a powerful tool.

Comment: Jeff Cavalier is a snake oil salesman.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The widely used term I've heard for this is an "overwarm single", as in warming up *past* the working set weight with a single rep set. If they're done for a double then obviously the term would have to change :)

This has mental benefits similar to supermaximal walk-outs for squats, where the lifter loads the bar beyond what they could squat and only sets up for a rep they don't actually do, before putting the bar back. These are used to get comfortable with the sensation of a very heavy bar, so it doesn't surprise or intimidate the lifter.

Overwarm singles may also help through post-activation potentiation. That is, doing a heavy rep signals to and prepares the body to perform better (more explosively, recruiting more available strength) on lighter reps.

The part where he uses a box squat to warm up for a non-box squat is new to me. Maybe it works.

Comment: Is this essentially the same thing as a top set? Say I hit a 1x3 for a heavy weight and then follow it up with a 5x5.

Comment: @C.Lange Similar concept to using a 1@8 to assess preparedness for the work sets and determine working weights.

Comment: I think the distinction with a top set is just intent, or in other words...yeah I guess it is the same thing :)